# Adding elements to an ArrayList and if the element have the same value in the ArrayList, it can't be added

Tags: java, arraylist

I am developing a search system. I have this problem with same Coordinate getting add more than once into the search queue. I've add some if statements to filter out these problem but it still occur and I have no idea why. I've not found a way to use `LinkedHashSet` because I tried to add new object into the list.

```
    package pathFinding;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

    public class SearchOld {
    public static Boolean pathFind(Coord start, Coord end /*, ArraList<Coord> blocked*/){

        boolean arrive = false;
        boolean way = false;

        ArrayList<Node> openList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Node> adjNode = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Coord> emptyList = new ArrayList<Coord>();

        int num = 0;
        Node startNode = new Node(start, start);
        closedList.add(startNode);
        openList.add(startNode);
        System.out.println(openList.get(0).getCoord().getX() + " " + openList.get(0).getCoord().getY());
        a:{while(!arrive){
            all:{for(int i = 0;i<openList.size();i++){
                if(end.getX() == openList.get(i).getCoord().getX() && end.getY() == openList.get(i).getCoord().getY()){
                    arrive = true;
                    break all;
            }
            adjNode.addAll(Adjacent.findAdjacent(openList.get(0).getCoord()));
                for(int j=0;j<adjNode.size();j++){
                    check:{for(int k = 0;k<openList.size();k++){
                        if(adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getX() == openList.get(k).getCoord().getX() && adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getY() == openList.get(k).getCoord().getY()){
                            adjNode.remove(0);
                            System.err.println("X" + adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getX() + "Y" + adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getY());
                            arrive = true;
                            break check;
                        }else{
                            for(int l = 0;l<closedList.size();l++){
                                if(adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getX() == closedList.get(l).getCoord().getX() && adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getY() == closedList.get(l).getCoord().getY()){
                                    /*if(end.getX() == adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getX() && end.getY() == adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getY()){
                                        openList.add(adjNode.get(0));
                                        closedList.add(adjNode.get(0));
                                        break all;
                                }*/
                                    adjNode.remove(0);
                                    break check;
                                }else{
                                    openList.add(adjNode.get(0));
                                    adjNode.remove(0);
                                    break check;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                }
            closedList.add(openList.get(0));
            openList.remove(0);
            LinkedHashSet<Node> tempSet = new LinkedHashSet<Node>();
            tempSet.addAll(closedList);
            closedList.clear();
            closedList.addAll(tempSet);
        };}

    };}

        //Coordinate got add many times
        for(int m = 0;m<closedList.size();m++){
            if(closedList.get(m).getCoord().getX() != closedList.get(m).getParent().getX() || closedList.get(m).getCoord().getY() != closedList.get(m).getParent().getY()){
            System.out.println("X"+closedList.get(m).getCoord().getX()+"Y"+closedList.get(m).getCoord().getY() +"Parent X" + closedList.get(m).getParent().getX() + "Y" + closedList.get(m).getParent().getY());
        }else{
            System.err.println("X"+closedList.get(m).getCoord().getX()+"Y"+closedList.get(m).getCoord().getY() +"Parent X" + closedList.get(m).getParent().getX() + "Y" + closedList.get(m).getParent().getY());

            }
        };
        System.out.println(closedList.size());
        System.out.println(arrive);
        //return closedList;
        return arrive;
    }
}
```

Class **Adjacent.java**

```
public static ArrayList<Node> findAdjacent(Coord coord){
    ArrayList<Node> adj = new ArrayList<Node>();

    if(coord.getX() > 1){
        Node left = new Node(new Coord(coord.getX()-1, coord.getY()), coord);
        adj.add(left);
    }
    if(coord.getX() < 25){
        Node right = new Node(new Coord(coord.getX()+1, coord.getY()), coord);
        adj.add(right);
    }
    if(coord.getY() > 1){
        Node up = new Node(new Coord(coord.getX(), coord.getY()-1), coord);
        adj.add(up);
    }
    if(coord.getY() < 25){
        Node down = new Node(new Coord(coord.getX(), coord.getY()+1), coord);
        adj.add(down);
    }
    return adj;

}
```

The ones in comments mean that I will add later when this problem is fixed. Thanks for helping.

**[EDIT]**
I've now tried @Dhiraj suggestion on changing the comparing method for comparing Coordinates. But the result is still the same, coordinates getting add to the search queue more than once. I've also clean up the code a bit.

Class **Search.java**:

```
package pathFinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class Search {
public static Boolean pathFind(Coord start, Coord end /*, ArraList<Coord> blocked*/){

        boolean arrive = false;
        boolean way = false;

        ArrayList<Node> openList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Node> adjNode = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Coord> emptyList = new ArrayList<Coord>();

        int num = 0;
        Node startNode = new Node(start, start);
        closedList.add(startNode);
        openList.add(startNode);
        System.out.println(openList.get(0).getCoord().getX() + " " + openList.get(0).getCoord().getY());
        a:{while(arrive == false){
            if(CheckList.checkCoordInNodeArray(openList, end) || CheckList.checkCoordInNodeArray(closedList, end)){
                arrive = true;
                break;
            }
            all:{for(int i = 0;i<openList.size();i++){
                adjNode.addAll(Adjacent.findAdjacent(openList.get(0).getCoord()));
                for(int j=0;j<adjNode.size();j++){
                    if(CheckList.checkCoordInNodeArray(adjNode, end)){
                        arrive = true;
                        break all;
                    }
                    if(CheckList.checkCoordInNodeArray(openList, adjNode.get(0).getCoord()) == false || CheckList.checkCoordInNodeArray(closedList, adjNode.get(0).getCoord()) == false){
                        System.out.println("o " + CheckList.checkCoordInNodeArray(openList, adjNode.get(0).getCoord()) + " X" + adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getX() + "Y" + adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getY());
                        System.out.println("c " + CheckList.checkCoordInNodeArray(closedList, adjNode.get(0).getCoord())+ " X" + adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getX() + "Y" + adjNode.get(0).getCoord().getY());
                        openList.add(adjNode.get(0));
                        adjNode.remove(0);
                        break;
                    }else{

                        adjNode.remove(0);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                closedList.add(openList.get(0));
                openList.remove(0);
                LinkedHashSet<Node> tempSet = new LinkedHashSet<Node>();
                tempSet.addAll(closedList);
                closedList.clear();
                closedList.addAll(tempSet);
            };}

        };}

        //Coordinate got add many times
        System.out.println("CSIZE" + closedList.size());
        for(int m = 0;m<closedList.size();m++){
            if(closedList.get(m).getCoord().getX() != closedList.get(m).getParent().getX() || closedList.get(m).getCoord().getY() != closedList.get(m).getParent().getY()){
                System.out.println("X"+closedList.get(m).getCoord().getX()+"Y"+closedList.get(m).getCoord().getY() +"Parent X" + closedList.get(m).getParent().getX() + "Y" + closedList.get(m).getParent().getY());
            }else{
                System.err.println("X"+closedList.get(m).getCoord().getX()+"Y"+closedList.get(m).getCoord().getY() +"Parent X" + closedList.get(m).getParent().getX() + "Y" + closedList.get(m).getParent().getY());

            }
        };
        System.out.println(closedList.size());
        System.out.println(arrive);
        //return closedList;
        return arrive;
    }
}
```

**[EDIT2]**
Here's my **CheckList.java**

```
package pathFinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CheckList {

    public static boolean checkNodeArray(ArrayList<Node> ar, Node no){
        boolean ava = true;
        for(Node node : ar){
            if(no.equals(node.getCoord())){
                ava  = true;
            }else{
                ava = false;
            }
        }
        return ava;
    }

    public static boolean checkCoordInNodeArray(ArrayList<Node> ar, Coord Coor){
        boolean ava = true;
        for(Node node : ar){
            if(Node.compareNodeCoord(Coor, node)){
                ava  = true;
            }else{
                ava = false;
            }
        }
        return ava;
    }

    public static Coord findCoordInNodeArray(ArrayList<Node> ar, Coord Coor){
        Coord coor = Coor;
        for(Node node : ar){
            if(Node.compareNodeCoord(Coor, node) == true){
                coor = node.getParent();
                break;
            }else{

            }
        }
        if(coor == Coor){
            System.err.println("NotFound");
        }
        return coor;
    }
}
```

And here are my `compareNodeCoord()`

```
public static boolean compareNodeCoord(Node node1, Node node2){
        boolean equal = false;
        if(node1.equals(node2.getCoord())){
            equal = true;
        }else{
            equal = false;
        }
        return equal;
    }
    public static boolean compareNodeCoord(Coord coor1, Node node2){
        boolean equal = false;
        if(coor1.equals(node2.getCoord())){
            equal = true;
        }else{
            equal = false;
        }
        return equal;
    }
```

This problem isn't very big a first but when I start to increase the size of the block traveled, the program will be stuck in an very very long loop.

Sorry if this looks messy. I am very new here and also very new to programming using Java.

Comment: post your CheckList class too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the `equals` method to compare the object.
 Please refer the below code as for same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coordinates c1 = new Coordinates(10, 15);
        List<Coordinates> coordinatesList = new ArrayList<>();
        coordinatesList.add(c1);

        Coordinates c2 = new Coordinates(10, 15);
        for(Coordinates coordinate:coordinatesList ){
        if (coordinate.equals(c2)) {
            System.out.println("Equal ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Equal ");
        }
        }
    }
```

And Coordinates class will be as below

```
class Coordinates{
    private double x, y;    

    public Coordinates(double x, double y) {
        this.x= x;
        this.y= y;
    }

     // Overriding equals() to compare two Complex objects
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        // If the object is compared with itself then return true  
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        /* Check if o is an instance of Complex or not
          "null instanceof [type]" also returns false */
        if (!(o instanceof Coordinates)) {
            return false;
        }

        // typecast o to Complex so that we can compare data members 
        Coordinates c = (Coordinates) o;

        // Compare the data members and return accordingly 
        return Double.compare(x, c.x) == 0
                && Double.compare(y, c.y) == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with this, but the results are the same. Same coordinates are getting added into the openSet and as a result, the adjacent search searches the same coord more than once. I've tweak some of the code to run with your way.

Comment: you can use arrayList if you trying to use  my solution in it. You have used a lot of if statement instead of that just compare object using this way. Compare objects in list before adding new object to list. this will eliminate the chances of getting duplicate coordinates getting added in list.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Set instead of a List. No if's will be needed anymore. And on your own objects make sure they have their own hashCode and equals methods.

Comment: Using a Set collection will require each element to be unique, but won't necessarily retain ordering.

Comment: There are orderedsets too.